# Problema al sumar millones en una tabla replace jquery

Tags: jquery

Actualmente tomo todos los valores de la segunda columna los sumo y les quito los "$" y los ".", solo funciona cuando son números de 6 dígitos al colocar en la tabla números de 7 dígitos la suma se realiza mal, ¿a que se puede deber ? a mi parecer estoy haciendo mal el replace gracias.

```js
var Total = 0;
$('#table_vehiculos tbody > tr').each(function() {
  let precio = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text().replace(/\$/, '').replace(/\./, '');
  Total += Number(precio);
});
alert(Total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_vehiculos">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Modelo</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>chevrolet</td>
      <td>$2.000.000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>suzuki</td>
      <td>$6.000.000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya que estas usando `.replace()` con Regex la forma como lo haces se puede simplificar, de tener:

```
$(this).find('td:eq(1)').text().replace(/\$/, '').replace(/\./, '');
```

se puede hacer de esta forma:

```
$(this).find('td:eq(1)').text().replace(/(\$|\.)/g, '');
```

estoy indicando que se remplace todo `$` o `.` del texto, pero le añado `g` para que la búsqueda sea global, osea, que busca todas las coincidencias

```js
var Total = 0;
$('#table_vehiculos tbody > tr').each(function() {
  let precio = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text().replace(/(\$|\.)/g, '');
  Total += Number(precio);
});
alert(Total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_vehiculos">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Modelo</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>chevrolet</td>
      <td>$2.000.000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>suzuki</td>
      <td>$6.000.000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias estimado !

Answer (score 0):

También puedes usar [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```js
var Total = 0;
var expresion_regular = RegExp('[\$,\.]', 'g');

$('#table_vehiculos tbody > tr').each(function() {
  let precio = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text().replace(expresion_regular, '');
  Total += Number(precio);
});
alert(Total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_vehiculos">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Modelo</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>chevrolet</td>
      <td>$2.000.000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>suzuki</td>
      <td>$6.000.000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Por cierto, `g` (global match) es usado para reemplazar **todas** las ocurrencias. He sacado la expresión regular fuera del loop ya que no es necesario compilarla en cada iteración.